# Return value in array and print it

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, return

I need to return all values in array `T`  in `taylor_tan()` and print it in function `myprint()` or should I use `T` as pointer? If yes, can you tell me how?

```
void myprint(char *argv[],double x)
{
      int j = atoi(argv[4]);
      int n = atoi(argv[3]);
      double T[13] = taylor_tan(x,n);
      double M = tang(x);
      double C = taylor_tan(x,n);

   for(int i = n; i <= j; i++)
   {
      printf("%d %e %e %e %e %e\n", i , M , T[i] , M - T[i] , C , M - C);
   }
}

double taylor_tan(double x,int n)
{ 
   double a [13] = {1, 1, 2, 17, 62, 1382, 21844, 929569, 6404582, 443861162, 18888466084}       
   double b [13] = {1, 3, 15, 315, 2835, 155925, 6081075, 638512875, 10854718875, 1856156927625}
   int i = 0;
   int k = -1;
   double D = 0;
   double T[13];

 if((x >= 0) && (x <= 1.4))                     //kontroluje ci je x v spravnom intervale
 {
    for (i = 0 ; i < 13 ; i++)
    {   
     n++;
     k += 2;
     D = D + ((a[i] * (square(x,k))) / b[i] );  
     T[i] = D;                      
   //printf("%.10e\n", T[i]);
    }
  }
 else 
 {
   printf("error\n");    
   return -1;
  }
return T[i];
}
```

Comment: Not sure if "taylor_tan" stands for taylor series or an actress.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a complete answer, as it is impossible for me to test if it works, but first:

```
   double a [13] = {1, 1, 2, 17, 62, 1382, 21844, 929569, 6404582, 443861162, 18888466084}; \\don't forget the ;       
   double b [13] = {1, 3, 15, 315, 2835, 155925, 6081075, 638512875, 10854718875, 1856156927625}; \\don't forget the ;
```

Then for the original question. You have to pass a pointer to the array you want to get the values into to the function taylor_tan

change in the myprint

```
  double* T;
  double M = tang(x);
  double C = taylor_tan(x,n, &T);
```

and change the function parameters of taylor_tan like this:

```
double taylor_tan(double x,int n, double** T1)
```

and in the taylor_tan include either in the beginning or before returning

```
*T1=T;
```

hope this will help.